# Looping through column based on comparing dates, if less than today then lookup previous columns

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I understand that a match function is needed to look up values to the left rather than a right (VLOOKUP).

My want to click the macro button to display the items of the previous two columns, if the cell (is past its due date), and build an array of items which are past its due date.

```
Sub ItemRegister()
    Application.Workbooks("Current.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
On Error GoTo MyErrorHandler:
Dim Today As Date
Dim InspectionDate As Range
Dim ItemRow As Long
Dim ItemCol As Long
Dim Check As Variant
Today = Date
Set InspectionDate = [G4:G500]
Set TableC = [A4:A500]
Set TableS = [B4:B500]
Set DateArray = [G4:G500]
ItemRow = [G4].Row
ItemCol = [G4].Column
For Each Cell In InspectionDate
    Check = Application.Match(Cell, DateArray, 0) 'need to fix match up
If Cell = "" Then
    Item = ""
    Serial = ""
    If Cell <= Today Then
        Item = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(TableC, Check)
        Serial = Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(TableS, Check)
        Else
            Item = ""
            Serial = ""
    End If
    ItemRow = ItemRow + 1
End If
Next Cell
Exit Sub
MyErrorHandler:
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "An error has occured - please ensure that cells have not been altered in anyway - Something is wrong with code, Debug It" 'Remove this, when process is completed
Else
MsgBox "The item(s) that need inspection is/are: " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Item & "-" & Serial
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you could adopt an [`AutoFilter()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) approach;

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim area As Range
    Dim iCell As Long

    With Application.Workbooks("Current.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1") '<--| reference relevant worksheeu
        With .Range("G3", .Cells(.Rows.COUNT, "G").End(xlUp).Offset(1)) '<-- reference its column "G" cell from row 3 down to last not empty cell
            .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<=" & CDbl(Date) '<--| filter referenced column on dates preceeding or equal today's date
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Cells) > 1 Then '<--| if any cell filtered other than header (which is in row 3)
                With .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) '<--| reference columnn "G" filtered cells
                    ReDim Item(1 To .COUNT) '<--| size Item array to the number of referenced (i.e. filtered) cells
                    ReDim Serial(1 To .COUNT) '<--| size Serial array to the number of referenced (i.e. filtered) cells
                    For Each cell In .Cells '<--| loop through referenced (i.e. filtered) cells
                        iCell = iCell + 1 '<--| update cell counter
                        Item(iCell) = cell.Offset(, -6).Value '<--| retrieve value in column "A" cell at current filtered cell row
                        Serial(iCell) = cell.Offset(, -5).Value '<--| retrieve value in column "G" cell at current filtered cell row
                    Next cell
                End With
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False '<--| show all rows back
    End With
End Sub
```